# Configure SonarQube (Node.JS) to download binaries from an internal server

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, binaryfiles

What we are trying to do is to get SonarQube to analyze our Typescript (Node.JS) project on a Docker image, but we are running into an error. If it helps, we are trying to use the sonarqube-scanner module from Node.JS.

The error is as encountered below:

```
[17:57:23] Starting analysis...
[17:57:24] Getting info from "package.json" file
[17:57:24] Checking if executable exists: /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-4.5.0.2216-linux/bin/sonar-scanner
[17:57:24] Could not find executable in "/root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner".
[17:57:24] Proceed with download of the platform binaries for SonarScanner...
[17:57:24] Creating /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner
[17:57:24] Downloading from https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.5.0.2216-linux.zip
[17:57:24] (executable will be saved in cache folder: /root/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner)
[91m[18:03:53] [0m[91mERROR: impossible to download and extract binary: connect ETIMEDOUT 91.134.125.245:443
[0m[91m[18:03:53] [0m[91m       SonarScanner binaries probably don't exist for your OS (linux).
[0m[91m[18:03:53]        In such situation, the best solution is to install the standard SonarScanner (requires a JVM).
[0m[91m[18:03:53]        Check it out at https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner.html
```

Now if you notice from the error, the binaries server encounters an ETIMEDOUT error, and this is because the server that accesses it comes from an internal network that cannot access external sites.

Would it be possible to configure SonarQube to pull from an internal server? And if so how would we go about configurating this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I still can access the link: https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.5.0.2216-linux.zip (it has ip address 91.134.125.245). looks like your sonar behind proxy or firewall

Comment: Yes it is behind a proxy/firewall. Is there a way to configure the binary source url?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find documentation through the SonarQube Javascript module here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner)

By default, the scanner binaries are downloaded from https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/. To use a custom mirror, set $SONAR_SCANNER_MIRROR. Or download precise version with $SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION

Example:

export SONAR_SCANNER_MIRROR=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/sonar-scanner/
export SONAR_SCANNER_VERSION=3.2.0.1227